# C# Syntax without class instantiation

Tags: c#, syntax

I'm working through the sorts in C# and right now writing up a quicksort and seem to have the syntax incorrect.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SortQuick
{
class quickSortAlgorithm
{
    private int[] array = new int[10];
    private int len;
    public static void quicksort(int left, int right)
    {
        int pivot;
        pivot = array[left];

        while(left < right)
        {
            while (array[left] <= pivot & (left<right)) {
                --right;
            }
            if(left != right)
            {
                array[left] = array[right];
                left++;
            }
            while((array[left]>= pivot) & (left>right)) {
                left++;
            }

            if(left!=right)
            {
                array[right] = array[left];
                right--;
            }
        }
        array[left] = pivot;
        pivot = left;
       if(left<pivot)
        {
            quicksort(left, pivot);
        }
       if(right>pivot)
        {
            quicksort(pivot+1, right);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        quickSortAlgorithm qSort = new quickSortAlgorithm();
        int[] array = { 32, 43, 54, 65, 23, 56, 34, 78, 98, 12};
        qSort.array = array;
        qSort.len = qSort.array.Length;
        quicksort(0, qSort.len - 1);
        for (int j = 0; j &lt; qSort.len;++j) {
            Console.WriteLine(qSort.array[j]);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

The compiler is not happy about the array within the function and then also the escape condition in the loop in main. I have written this myself without a constructor but the errors that I am getting are something I can get to go away I just don't understand the difference in the syntax.

```
/*
*  C# Program to Implement Quick Sort
*/
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace sortQuickAlgorithm
{
class quickSortAlgorithm
{

    private int[] array = new int[20];
    private int len;

    public void QuickSortAlgorithm()
    {
        sort(0, len - 1);
    }

    public void sort(int left, int right)
    {
        int pivot, leftend, rightend;

        leftend = left;
        rightend = right;
        pivot = array[left];

        while (left < right)
        {
            while ((array[right] >= pivot) & amp; &amp; (left < right))
            {
                right--;
            }

            if (left != right)
            {
                array[left] = array[right];
                left++;
            }

            while ((array[left] >= pivot) & amp; &amp; (left < right))
            {
                left++;
            }

            if (left != right)
            {
                array[right] = array[left];
                right--;
            }
        }

        array[left] = pivot;
        pivot = left;
        left = leftend;
        right = rightend;

        if (left < pivot) { sort(left, pivot - 1); }
        if (right > pivot)
        {
            sort(pivot + 1, right);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        quickSortAlgorithm q_Sort = new quickSortAlgorithm();

        int[] array = { 41, 32, 15, 45, 63, 72, 57, 43, 32, 52, 183 };
        q_Sort.array = array;
        q_Sort.len = q_Sort.array.Length;
        q_Sort.QuickSortAlgorithm();

        for (int j = 0; j & lt; q_Sort.len; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(q_Sort.array[j]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
     }
  }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, 
method, or property 'quickSortAlgorithm.array'  SortQuick    
C:\Program.cs   15  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'j' does not exist in the current context  SortQuick    
C:\SortQuick\SortQuick\Program.cs   55  Active
Error   CS1026  ) expected  SortQuick   C:\SortQuick\SortQuick\Program.cs    
 55 Active
Error   CS1002  ; expected  SortQuick   C:\SortQuick\SortQuick\Program.cs    
55  Active
Error   CS1513  } expected  SortQuick   C:\SortQuick\SortQuick\Program.cs    
55  Active
Error   CS1026  ) expected  Miscellaneous Files C:\C#\Practice\Class1.cs     
32  Active
Error   CS1002  ; expected  Miscellaneous Files C:\C#\Practice\Class1.cs     
32  Active
Error   CS1513  } expected  Miscellaneous Files C:\C#\Practice\Class1.cs     
32  Active
Error   CS1026  ) expected  Miscellaneous Files C:\C#\Practice\Class1.cs     
43  Active
Error   CS1002  ; expected  Miscellaneous Files C:\C#\Practice\Class1.cs     
43  Active
Error   CS1513  } expected  Miscellaneous Files C:\C#\Practice\Class1.cs     
43  Active
Error   CS1026  ) expected  Miscellaneous Files C:\C#\Practice\Class1.cs     
76  Active
Error   CS1002  ; expected  Miscellaneous Files C:\C#\Practice\Class1.cs     
76  Active
 Error  CS1513  } expected  Miscellaneous Files C:\C#\Practice\Class1.cs     
 76 Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'lt' does not exist in the current context SortQuick    
C:\SortQuick\SortQuick\Program.cs   55  Active
Error   CS0201  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new 
object expressions can be used as a statement   SortQuick    
C:\Program.cs   55  Active
 Error  CS0103  The name 'j' does not exist in the current context  SortQuick    
C:\Program.cs   56  Active
 Message    IDE1006 Naming rule violation: These words must begin with upper 
case 
characters: quickSortAlgorithm  SortQuick   C:\Program.cs   8   Active
 Message    IDE1006 Naming rule violation: These words must begin with upper 
 case 
 characters: quicksort  SortQuick   C:\Program.cs   12  Active
```

Comment: Did you read the compiler's error message? You have a static method trying to access an instance field.

Comment: @madreflection Even if the method is not static the exact same error.

Comment: @madreflection so with a method able to access the instance field. I called the correct 'public void quickSort(int left, int right)' with 'qSort.quickSort(0, qSort.len-1);' and the compiler still says my loop conditions do not pass the checker.

Comment: Please post the *actual* message.

Comment: Do you really have "`& amp; &amp;`" and "`& lt;`" in your code? That could cause those errors. You know how to fix the first one already because the second version doesn't get it.

Comment: @madreflection no that was the reason I wanted to work through the problem with Java OOP my language of choice a lot I am trying to not get the syntax confused and it happens to be very challenging when I thought it would be the easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing `QuickSort(0, qSort.len - 1);` from `static void Main(string[] args)`. The compiler thinks that you are trying to call a non-static method from a static scope.

I believe what you really want is to execute `qSort.QuickSort(0, qSort.len - 1);`.

The difference here is that it is clear to the compiler what instance of the QuickSort object to call the `QuickSort` method on.

Imagine if you had made multiple QuickSortAlgorithm objects in your Main method. If you just called `QuickSort` then how would it know which instance to execute this method for?

I think having your algorithm implementation within the same class as your static program entry-point, `main`, is confusing things. You might find the error easier to recognize if you separate things out:

```
using System;

namespace Algorithms
{
    public class Sort
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            QuickSortAlgorithm qSort = new QuickSortAlgorithm();
            int[] array = { 32, 43, 54, 65, 23, 56, 34, 78, 98, 12};
            qSort.array = array;
            qSort.len = qSort.array.Length;

            // This isn't going to work, the QuickSortAlgorithm class doesn't have a static definition for this method.
            // Beyond that, our implementation of the QuickSort method references instance variables, which are not referencable from a static scope.
            QuickSortAlgorithm.QuickSort(0, qSort.len - 1);

            for (int j = 0; j < qSort.len;++j)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(qSort.array[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public class QuickSortAlgorithm
    {
        // These are instance variables; i.e. they belong to an instance of QuickSortAlgorithm, not the static class.
        public int[] array = new int[10]; // <-- changed to public
        public int len; // <-- changed to public
        public void QuickSort(int left, int right)
        {
            int pivot;
            pivot = array[left];

            while(left < right)
            {
                while (array[left] <= pivot & (left<right)) {
                --right;
                }

                if(left != right)
                {
                    array[left] = array[right];
                    left++;
                }
                while((array[left]>= pivot) & (left>right))
                {
                    left++;
                }

                if(left!=right)
                {
                    array[right] = array[left];
                    right--;
                }
            }

            array[left] = pivot;
            pivot = left;

            if(left<pivot)
            {
                QuickSort(left, pivot);
            }

            if(right>pivot)
            {
                QuickSort(pivot+1, right);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is is a bit more clear that what we really want is not to call the static `QuickSortAlgorithm.QuickSort(0, qSort.len - 1);`, but rather the method on the instance by `qSort.QuickSort(0, qSort.len - 1);`

Comment: @JefferyJ I completely get what you are saying my question still persists in that I know designing the two classes gets the result though the given approach has the result set in using everything in one class and want to know if that is possible?